# how Can I show the principal symbol of the differential operator is not elliptic?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

Let us assume the principal symbol of a nonlinear differential operator $E$ at a point $p$ is
$$\sigma‎_{‎E‎}(p):‎\Gamma (‎T^*M‎)\times \Gamma (T^*‎M‎)\to \Gamma (T^*‎M‎)‎$$‎
which acts as follows:
‎‎‎\begin{align}
‎\sigma_{E}(‎p‎) ‎(a,\eta)‎ &‎=‎‎‎‎ \sum_{k,l=1}^n ‎‎‎‎\Big(‎ a_k a_l‎\alpha_i‎\eta_j ‎+ a_k a_l ‎\eta‎_i\alpha‎_j -a_i a_k\alpha_l‎\eta_j- a_i a_k\eta‎_l\alpha‎_j\\‎
‎&‎-a_ja_k‎‎\alpha_l \eta_i-a_j a_k‎\eta‎_l\alpha_i ‎+‎‎a_i a_j\alpha_k ‎\eta_l ‎+a_i a_j\eta‎_k\alpha‎_l \Big)‎ \xi^j \\‎
‎&‎-‎‎ 2\rho \Big(‎a^t‎ a_t ‎\alpha_k‎ ‎\eta_l‎ +‎a^t ‎a_t ‎‎\eta_k ‎\alpha_l‎ -‎a^ta^s ‎\alpha_t \eta_s -‎a‎^ta^s ‎\alpha_s‎ \eta_t‎‎ ‎\Big)\alpha_i‎
\end{align}
In above the Einstein summation convention is used and $\rho$ is a real scalar.

> The Problem is: I want to show this equation is not  strictly parabolic.

I put $a=(1,0,\cdots ,0)$ and $\eta=(1,0,\cdots ,0))$. With this assumptions I only can show the first part is equal to zero.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.